# How to change date range which was entered as a parameter

Tags: crystal-reports

for my evaluation I have set a date range as an input parameter. This chosen date range should be displayed in a textbox (by using a formula field for example).

What I reached so far is, that I choose a date range and CR goes through the corresponding data.
But I can only see the first and last date on which something happenend.

Example:

Entered Date range:                          01.01.2019 - 16.10.2019
First/last date with a created notification: 03.01.2019 - 14.10.2019
Displayed date range:                        03.01.2019 - 14.10.2019

This could cause confusion because it looks like we evaluated a shorter date period.

Is there a method to just show the entered parameters?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you have that parameter on the report and when you input that date range it modifies it somehow or is it the data that only starts at 03/01 ? Check you data source if there's data between 01/01/2019 and 03/01/2019

Comment: There are no actions before 03/01 but I want to display the date period from the 01/01. Otherwise our customers will think, that we only evaluated from the 03/01.

Comment: Take a look at this picture, maybe it gets clearer then:
https://ibb.co/Qjbb7Zq

Isn´t there a function to just access the parameters i insert on the left? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing the parameters in a formula and displaying them as this may be causing your issue.  Do the following;

Get a textbox and place it in the report header.  On the right in your field explorer, expand the Parameter Fields and drag the DateFrom and DateTo in the textbox.  Something like this;

[image]

Doing so will display the entered range in the parameter and not the range values actually exist for.

Comment: I don´t have the parameter field {?DateFrom} and {?DateTo}..
Are these standard fields?

Comment: To select my data, I´m using the "Date" standard parameter field (https://ibb.co/tPMB2yK), which allows me to enter a range of dates: https://ibb.co/HYDGkZq.
I´m sorry, my pictures are only in german language.

Comment: They are not standard fields but custom parameters you must create.